# How to make an image of a YouTube video appear as a thumbnail in the list of blog posts

Tags: youtube

How do I post a YouTube video so that an image of the video also appears as a thumbnail in the list of posts.

Here's the blog in case that helps: http://wordfruit.com/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MayBe This Plugin can help you out :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-thumbnails/

> But if you want to do this manually then you can get Video Image from
>   this Link :

http://img.youtube.com/vi/SgGVitTU9F8/0.jpg
Replace "SgGVitTU9F8" to your video id